# Application stopped suddenly

Tags: android

My application is based on displaying the current location to the user. 
so in my MainActivity.java i put a locate button.
 but when i run the app and press locate button, my app stops.

My Gps.java

```
package com.shalu.alzcare;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class Gps extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

GoogleMap googleMap;
Button sendBtn;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available
    int requestCode = 10;
Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
dialog.show();
}else
{ 
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
googleMap = fm.getMap();
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
if(location!=null){
       onLocationChanged(location);
}
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
}
sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
 public void onClick(View view) {
    sendSMSMessage();
 }
});
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +latitude+ ", Longitude:"+longitude);
}
   protected void sendSMSMessage() {
    Log.i("Send SMS", "");  
    String con1="9876543210";
    try {
       SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
       smsManager.sendTextMessage(con1, null, "I am Out please call me!!", null, null);
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
       "SMS faild, please try again.",
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

My Activity_gps.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:text="Help" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.shalu.alzcare"
        android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

 <permission android:name="com.shalu.alzcare.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.shalu.alzcare.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Contacts"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contacts"
            android:parentActivityName=".Login" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.shalu.alzcare.Login" />

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Reminder"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reminder"
            android:parentActivityName=".Contacts" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.shalu.alzcare.Contacts" />

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Details"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_details"
            android:parentActivityName=".Reminder" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.shalu.alzcare.Reminder" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Gps"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gps"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.shalu.alzcare.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
         <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <receiver android:name=".DeviceBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="My API" />
    </application>



</manifest>
```

previously it was showing me null pointer exception and now runtime exception

Log File

```
04-17 20:15:36.956: E/AndroidRuntime(24437): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shalu.alzcare/com.shalu.alzcare.Gps}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
04-17 20:15:36.956: E/AndroidRuntime(24437):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
04-17 20:15:36.956: E/AndroidRuntime(24437): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
04-17 20:15:36.956: E/AndroidRuntime(24437):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:372)
04-17 20:15:36.956: E/AndroidRuntime(24437):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2046)
04-17 20:15:36.956: E/AndroidRuntime(24437):    at com.shalu.alzcare.Gps.onCreate(Gps.java:30)
04-17 20:15:36.956: E/AndroidRuntime(24437): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
04-17 20:15:36.956: E/AndroidRuntime(24437): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
04-17 20:15:36.956: E/AndroidRuntime(24437):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
04-17 20:15:36.956: E/AndroidRuntime(24437):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
04-17 20:15:36.956: E/AndroidRuntime(24437):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
```

Comment: which is the button? i cant see the called activity when you press your button... please put the method called (in button press). And your button does nothing in your .xml.

Comment: that button in .xml file, sends msg

Comment: its no were related to gps or error

Answer (score 1):

Append `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` in your manifest file's `<application>` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.shalu.alzcare"
        android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

 <permission android:name="com.shalu.alzcare.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.shalu.alzcare.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Contacts"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contacts"
            android:parentActivityName=".Login" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.shalu.alzcare.Login" />

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Reminder"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reminder"
            android:parentActivityName=".Contacts" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.shalu.alzcare.Contacts" />

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Details"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_details"
            android:parentActivityName=".Reminder" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.shalu.alzcare.Reminder" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Gps"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gps"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.shalu.alzcare.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
         <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <receiver android:name=".DeviceBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="My_Api" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: 04-16 21:36:42.253: E/AndroidRuntime(20836): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7095000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Answer (score 1):

The logcat is saying it:

```
04-16 21:04:18.033: E/AndroidRuntime(18078): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7095000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Always look fot this **Caused by:** in the logcat, it should show you a enough information to find and correct a problem with your app, like in this case.

```
    The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  
Expected 7095000 but found 0.  
You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

So just do what it says, put this

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

inside the `<application>` tag in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

UPDATE:

As I said, you shuld look for this **Caused by**, here it is

```
04-17 20:15:36.956: E/AndroidRuntime(24437): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
04-17 20:15:36.956: E/AndroidRuntime(24437): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

See this:

```
The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

And now just add that permission to your AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: @Rai Shalu Can you post your new AndroidManifest, clean your project, rebuild it and post your new logcat?

Comment: i am really sorry for replying so late

Comment: it works but i want to display the location. But my page is entirely blank, only lat and longi is shown

Comment: @RaiShalu make sure you have the correct api key, and the map api activated in the api console.

Comment: Do i need to create a new keystore to get the correct api

Comment: Or i cn use debug.keystore for generating the Sha1 code

Comment: Right now i am using alzcare.keystore

Comment: @RaiShalu What is alzcare.keystore? You HAVE to use your debug.keystore, since you're debugging, if you realease the app you'll need the realease keystore.

Comment: I need one more help. Just scroll down, at the end i asked question to Mr Harsh.

Comment: Accept my answer, please. @RaiShalu , that's another question, you can ask it. But using SharedPreferences to save user's credentials when he/she log in will work. Just check for the SharedPreferences on the OnCreate of the LoginActivity and if they are already set, finish the activity and go for the map.

Comment: Now i dont have any kind of welcome activity which will the shared preference condition. So how to put condition and where. As if user open the app 2 nd time, he should see main activity not the login one

Comment: So do i need to put condition in login to check if he or she has logged in

Comment: @RaiShalu look at this example http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Comment: Can you send me the appropriate link or ans

Comment: @RaiShalu, yes because it is the first step that the user is taking on your app, that's what yo should do. every time you want to check a logged user, go for the first step taken in the app/web. Since yours is the login activity, check for the user's credentials, if set, go on,if not, just keep the activity so the user could log /register.

Answer (score 0):

Change in your Fragment tag, from

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

to

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

If this does not solve, then

Add meta-data within application element: Logcat clearly shows the error.

```
04-16 21:04:18.033: E/AndroidRuntime(18078): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7095000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Like This:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            ...
```

Comment: Add this permission in Manifest 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: I have another doubt.

Comment: I want to run my login and register activity only once. If user opens the application 2nd time then he should see the main activity not the login one

Comment: The problem is i dont have welcome page or any other page before login, were i can put any condition

Comment: You can use Shared Prefs to store user state, if he is logged in or not

Comment: So i should use this on my main page or login

Comment: Because the ans which I have seen, they use this pref on welcome page which is the 1st page. My 1st page itself is a login

Comment: But why don't create a Welcome screen! and use Shared Prefs on that Activity.